# Create a fixed ratio size view in Android

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'm trying to developed an app that can read card. For that i need to draw a card size ratio transparent box so that user can fit his/her card in that(eg : https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTgpU.png) . This box must be device independent. Also the image must be a fixed size like 450*300 for all devices.
Till now i'd created a drawable and called it in a view.

My Drawable code is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#88000000" />
</shape>
```

My main Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/cameraview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/myRectangleView"
            android:layout_width="337dp" 
            android:layout_height="213dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </FrameLayout>

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/capture"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:text="@string/Capture" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/image"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: So you do need a fixed RATIO image or fixed RESOLUTION image? Anyway just set its height and width in xml as 450dp and 300dp.

Comment: i want something like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/WTgpU.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

1. Get the device width and height in pixels.
2. Define the ratio of your view(according to the image its more like 0.9 of device width and 0.5 of device height)
3. Now you can calculate the required width and height of box

   ```
   width = 0.9 * device_width_pixels  ,   height = 0.5 * device_height_pixels
   ```
4. set the view dimensions  with calculated values.

Comment: how to set values of predefined view

Comment: why cant you change the dimentiones at runtime ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom `View` and override the `onMeasure` method.
For example for a square(1:1) `FrameLayout`:

```
public class SquareFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

    public SquareFrameLayout(final Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareFrameLayout(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareFrameLayout(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int width, int height) {
        super.onMeasure(width, height);
        int measuredWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredWidth);
    }

}
```